# Google Cloud Compute Engine - Nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I created a free server from Google Cloud. I want to run Node.js on this server. I installed Node.js. I installed Express and created a project. Then I run the project (working).

But I can not get the output by typing ip-address: 3000. "This site can not be reached." I get as a result.

What could be the reason for that.

Comment: Are you sure no sort of firewall or proxy is preventing you from accessing the server from port 3000?

Comment: How do I know that?

I build the server from scratch. Then I install Node.js. I create a project by installing an Express-generator. When I type "npm start" the project works but I can not access it from the browser. Is there a way to tell if the 3000 port is blocked?

Comment: try another port, like 80 or 8080

Comment: When I entered the port 80 "Index of /" looks.
When I enter the 8080 port, it returns the same result as the 3000 port, so it does not open.

Comment: You say "security wall" and I wanted to check out the Google Cloud panel.
"Create a firewall rule" by clicking the button I let the 3000 port. And the problem has improved.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just setup one to see how this works, how i setup the server, hope this helps:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Home Page');
})

app.listen(8080);
```

The web applications must listen for HTTP requests on ports within the permitted range 8080 to 8084.....To connect to a web application running on an instance, click the Web Preview button Web Preview Button above the Cloud Shell terminal window in the GCP Console.  src: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#web_preview

Comment: I wanted to check out the Google Cloud panel. "Create a firewall rule" by clicking the button I let the 3000 port. And the problem has improved. Thank you so much.